# What examples do we have of Susan Ivanova's latent telepathy?

Tags: babylon-5, telepathy

In season 2, episode 19 *“Divided Loyalties”*, CDR Ivanova confesses to CAPT John Sheridan of her telepathic abilities.

> **IVANOVA**:  I'm a latent telepath.
>   **SHERIDAN**:  Susan, why didn't you tell me this before?  I though we could trust each other.
>   **IVANOVA**:  It 's got nothing to do with *trust.*  I've spent my entire life hiding this, Captain.  It 's not something you can just *change* overnight.  It 's hard enough telling you this now.
>   **SHERIDAN**:  You're right.  I'm sorry.
>   **IVANOVA**:  For as long as I can remember, my mother drilled three words in to my head:  ‘Tell no one.’  She taught me how to fool the tests given at school, transferred me from one school to another — always staying one step ahead of the Psi Corps.  I'm probably not even a P1:  I've never been able to read anyone except my mother; I can pick–up on feelings, sometimes; I can block a casual scan — and I know instantly if someone 's doing it.  Nothing more.

What are the examples, as given in all of the canonical Babylon 5 stories, which seem to demonstrate or hint at Susan Ivanova using or having those abilities?
I would consider messages posted by J.M.S. to Usenet and which reveal otherwise undramatized character or backstory as canonical.

Answer (score 7):

## Television series

### season 1

- episode 16 *“Eyes”*

  > Harriman Gray, a telepath assigned to work with COL Ari ben-Zayn, is talking with Ivanova, then LCDR, in an attempt to gain her favor for expected telepathic scans to be conducted.
  >  > **GRAY**:  As for Psi Corps, I doubt you really know any of our people well — especially Ms Winters …
  >  > **IVANOVA**:  You're scanning me!
  >  > **GRAY**:  I'm sorry!  The thought of Ms Winters was very loud in your mind when I mentioned Psi Corps; I couldn't help but pick it up; please, forgive me.
  >  > (pause)  But, I am surprised you were aware of it.  Unless — of course:  she must've been in your mind numerous times before she was given the sleepers.  Your mother …

### season 2

- episode 19 *“Divided Loyalties”*

  > Lyta Alexander is attempting to send to Susan the telepathic code which would unlock the Sleeper personalty.
  >  > **LYTA**:  She 's blocking me.
  >  She does later get the code through.
  >  > **LYTA**:  She 's clean.  I'm sorry.
  >  > **IVANOVA**:  Go to hell.

### season 3

- episode 5 *“Voices of Authority”*

  > Ivanova ends up using the Great Machine of Epsilon III to track down a recording condemning President Clark, which Draal is stunned by and is convinced no normal human could do it.  Not directly linked to her latent telepathy, but strongly implied by Draal's reaction.

Comment: This covers two of the three things she said she can do: block and detect a casual scan. I wonder what evidence there is of her picking up on feelings.

Comment: There is also an episode (S3 I think) in which Bester visits B5, and Sheridan sends Ivanova to talk to him, with the idea that she will know if he tries to scan her.

Comment: @IanThompson that's 314, _”Ship of Tears”._  I would consider that an example of someone expecting her abilities to have an effect, rather than evidence of the abilities themselves; but, if you think it fits, go ahead and add it.

Comment: @Thunderforge: She fell in love with Lyta Alexander.

Comment: @Ernie I don't think that's sufficient evidence of her demonstrating telepathic abilities. She also fell in love with Marcus Cole, who most certainly is not a telepath, and had an ex-boyfriend come to the station once who also was not a telepath.

Comment: Well, there's little else to go on, now isn't there?

Comment: Actually, regarding Marcus — a good example of her _not_ catching someone else's feelings was when he told her that bit of Minbari, “You are the most beautiful woman I have ever seen.” and she didn't seem to notice his despondency.